# I need add new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to prepare a SQL report with 100 rows in the report. I need to add a new column to the report.

New column must have -  1's  in hundred rows.

```sql
Column Name
-----------
1
1
1
1
1
```

Need once like this in hundred rows how to achieve it in SQL Server.

Comment: Use a [Tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1).

Comment: Is that the output of a query or a base table?

Comment: `select *, 1 as newColumn from Table`

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Why would a report need (or show) a column that contains a fixed value for every row? This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most report tools will let you add a constant value to any band of the report without having to change the underlying datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need any logic applied and the extra column should be against ALL rows out put the format would be:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS newColumn FROM table
```